# Connect Google Analytics to Youtube analytics

Tags: google-analytics-api

I want to track my YouTube engagement with Google Analytics how do I connect my Youtube to Google Analytics? I have tried to obtain the tracking number of the Youtube channel and import it to Google Analytics but Im not sure where to embed it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube analytics and Google analytics are two separate applications which have no connection to eachother.

If you want to import data from YouTube analytics into your google analytics account you may want to check out the YouTube analytics api which will allow you to extract data from YouTube analytics.  Then you can check out the measurement protocol which will allow you to insert hits into Google analytics.

This will be something you will need to code yourselves.  TBH not sure why you would want to the data is not the same you will be comparing your website or application analytics with video performance. these things are  unrelated and should not be part of the same analytics.

Comment: I find it strange that there isn't an easier way to do this since Youtube and Google are basically the same company and you need a google account to have a youtube account. And the reason I want to connect my youtube analytics to Google is because I want all of my different data sources to be centralized to the same place. Im not a developer by any means Im a data scientist but I believe it should be possible to do this.

Comment: The fact remains that the YouTube analytics team and the Google analytics team have no relation to one another other than that their pay checks come from the same company.   If you want to link them you will need to do it yourself.